# PDDL2.1: Purpose of `over all`

Tags: planning, pddl

I'm working with PDDL2.1 durative-actions and I'm having difficulty understanding the purpose of `over all`.

I have a function `charge_level` which is updated with a value every 10Hz. In a durative-action `move`, I say `condition: (over all (>= (charge_level) 12))`.

I interpreted this as "while performing the action, verify that `charge_level` is greater than or equal to 12, otherwise, `move` fails and the planner should find a new action with the condition `at start (< (charge_level) 12)`". However, the planner does not seem to plan that way. I appreciate any clarity on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of the `over all` condition is indeed as @haz says in his answer (it prevents the planner from scheduling another action in parallel with your `move` action that would violate the `over all` condition), but what I think is confusing you is the difference between planning and plan execution. During plan execution, the `(charge_level)` may drop below `12` at any point unexpectedly due to malfunctioning battery, or faulty sensor, etc.. At such occasion, your plan execution should *stop* the `move` action (and therefore the whole plan) and re-plan. At that point, the planner could choose any action, which has a satisfied pre-condition in that new state. So not necessarily `at start (< (charge_level) 12)`.

The PDDL durative action cannot be stopped or paused by the planner, while computing the plan. However, if you tell the planner, how is the `(charge_level)` changing over time, it could compute the longest possible duration of the `move` action, and then do something else e.g. recharge battery, before scheduling another *instance* of the `move` action into the same plan. In that approach, there are no failures involved, just reasoning about how long a given action could last in order to achieve the goal without violating any constraints, including the `over all` conditions.

If that is the behavior you want, you will need to model the `(charge_level)` as a continuously changing function. If you want to see an example, here is the [power generator](https://github.com/jan-dolejsi/vscode-pddl-samples/tree/master/Generator)  or the [coffee machine](https://github.com/jan-dolejsi/vscode-pddl-samples/tree/master/CoffeeMachine). Here is a peek from the Generator domain:

The generator must not run out of fuel:

`(over all (>= (fuel-level ?g) 0))`

The fuel decreases by `1` unit every unit of time `#t`.

`(decrease (fuel-level ?g) (* #t 1))`

Given the initial `(fuel-level)`, it is a simple calculation to figure out the maximum duration of the action. For that flexibility, you will need to specify the action duration unconstrained `:duration (>= ?duration 0)`, as in the [coffee machine](https://github.com/jan-dolejsi/vscode-pddl-samples/tree/master/CoffeeMachine) domain.

Now, to be able to process such model including [continuous numeric effects](https://planning.wiki/ref/pddl21/domain#continuous-effects), you will need a planner that supports the `:continuous-effects` requirement, so for example [OPTIC](https://planning.wiki/ref/planners/optic), or [POPF](https://planning.wiki/ref/planners/popf).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent the action from happening based on a condition, then you use `at start`. The `over all` is for conditions that must hold for the full duration of the action. So you could interpret your condition as, "for the entire duration of moving, never let the battery level go below 12".

Comment: I've tried using `at start` and `over all` as conditions for the durative action. However, it doesn't seem to "stop" the action if the condition fails. I was hoping to find if there's a way to terminate a current action if the condition fails.

Comment: Might be worth running your plan through VAL to see what's going on -- there's likely a bug in the model that means the condition is satisfied in some weird way.